# Rails/Bootstrap - Flash notice :success is now red and not green?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, flash

I've been trying to search for an answer on here but I can't find anything that works. I have implemented a :success and :danger flash notice to my rails app. It WAS working completely fine, i.e :success was green and :danger was red, with a close button and all, BUT since adding some mailer files my :success is now showing up red??

application.html.erb excerpt:

```
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, class: "alert alert-#{key == 'notice ? 'success' : 'danger'}" do %>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <%= value %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <%= yield %>
  </div>

</body>
```

contact_mailer.rb

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: 'justindavidson23@gmail.com'

  def contact_email(name, phone, email, event_type, body)
    @name = name
    @phone = phone
    @email = email
    @event = event_type
    @body = body

    mail(from: email, subject: 'Contact Form Message').deliver
  end
end
```

contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      name = params[:contact][:name]
      phone = params[:contact][:phone]
      email = params[:contact][:email]
      event = params[:contact][:event_type]
      body = params[:contact][:comments]

      ContactMailer.contact_email(name, phone, email, event, body).deliver
      flash[:success] = 'Message Sent.'
      redirect_to new_contact_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Error occurred, messgage not sent.'
      redirect_to new_contact_path
    end
  end
end

private
def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :event_type, :comments)
end
```

and, contact_email.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>New Message from Hoot and Holla's Contact form, from <%= "#{@name}, #{@email}" %></p>
    <p><%= @phone %></p>
    <p><%= @event %></p>
    <p><%= @body %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I repeat that this was all working completely fine before the mailer stuff went in...but now i'm just baffled. Please help!

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: Are you using the bootstrap sass gem? And on a side note, you should put that mailer in a callback.

Comment: Hi Justin yes I am, and thanks for the tip!!..that would clean it up a lot!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sometimes you are going to want to use more than `notice` and `success`, like the [Bootstrap alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts-examples) `info`, `danger`, and `warning`.

Here is the solution I would recommend:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key %> alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <%= value %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

That way, when you call `flash[:success] = 'foo'`, your `key` would be `success`, and likewise for `info`, `warning`, `danger`, etc. This way you can utilize all of the different [Bootstrap alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts-examples).

With this method, you will have to add 2 more CSS classes, that extend the Bootstrap classes, *if* you want to use the syntax `notice: 'hello world',` or `alert: 'oops'` in your redirections, like `redirect_to root_url, notice: 'welcome home'`.

If you do want to use these, then you can use Sass, like below.

```
.alert-alert {
  @extend .alert-danger;
}

.alert-notice {
  @extend .alert-warning;
}
```

Since my comment earlier on the mailer callback was more of a side note and unrelated to this question, I made a [simple gist](https://gist.github.com/licatajustin/f348b5a5782bf5d38d35) for ya.

Comment: Oh that's great @JustinLicata! Cleans it up so much!(and simplifies). Thanks for taking the time to do this, really appreciate it!

Comment: `<div class="alert alert-<%= key %> alert-dismissible" role="alert">` adding the role attribute to help screen readers. The explanation is so nice @JustinLicata. It is so easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

In your flash loop, you are only checking flash[:notice] there. if there is flash[:notice], you applying `alert-success`. unless it applying `alert-danger`. So, what i change here. i am applying `alert-success` for both `flash[:success]` & `flash[:notice]`. So,
Do in _flash.html.erb -

```
  <%= content_tag :div, class: "alert alert-#{['success','notice'].include?(key) ? 'success' : 'danger'}" do %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in application layout...

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page-wrapper">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
 <%= content_tag(:div, msg, :id=>"#{name}", :class `enter code here`=>"alert alert-  info") %>
<%end%>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout(function() 
{
$("#notice").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function()
{
$(this).remove();
});
}, 5000);
</script>
<%= yield%>
```

Comment: Some explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Oh thanks so much @AmitSuroliya!! This has worked perfectly!! I'm trying to work out what is actually happening here in the code...i don't suppose you could give a short explanation as to why this works could you??...if not thankyou anyway!! I appreciate it so much :)

Justin

PS for people having the same problem and reading this....that solution was copying and pasting this into my application.html.erb file and replacing the content_tag line i had...NOT creating a partial called _flash.html.erb ..just incase anyone was getting confused there :)

Comment: Welcome Justin.......in your `flash` loop, you are only checking flash[:notice] there. if there is flash[:notice], you applying alert-success. unless it applying `alert-danger`. So, what i change here. i am applying `alert-success`  for  both `flash[:success] & flash[:notice].